# Django ModelForms: Seeding a FK related field in the form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a `Workshop` Django app. Each `Workshop` can have multiple attendees via a related `WorkshopAttendee` model (simplified below). I am using Django's `ModelForm` in a Class Based View, and in `forms.py` I am using [crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org):

**models.py (relevant parts)**

```python
class Workshop(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    information = models.TextField()
    location = models.TextField()

class WorkshopAttendee(models.Model):
    workshop = models.ForeignKey(Workshop)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**views.py (relevant parts)**

```python
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from workshop.forms import WorkshopAttendeeForm

class WorkshopAttendeeFormView(FormView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Clean the data
        form_data = form.cleaned_data
        form.save(commit=False)
        return super(WorkshopAttendeeFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**forms.py**

```python
from django.forms import ModelForm
from workshop.models import WorkshopAttendee
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, HTML, Field, \
    Fieldset, Button, Hidden, Submit, Reset
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import FormActions

# Create the form class
class WorkshopAttendeeForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Crispy form Layouts, Fieldsets, etc
        super(WorkshopAttendeeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = WorkshopAttendee
```

**urls.py (relevant parts)**

```python
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[\w\-.]+)/(?P<action>[\w\-.]+)/$',
        WorkshopAttendeeFormView.as_view(
            form_class=WorkshopAttendeeForm,
            success_url="success/",
            template_name='workshop/workshop_registration.html',
        ), name='workshop-attendee-register'
    ),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[\w\-.]+)/$',
        WorkshopDetailView.as_view(
            context_object_name='workshop_detail',
            queryset=Workshop.objects.select_related(),
            template_name='workshop/workshop_detail.html',
        ), name='workshop-detail'
    ),
)
```

My question is, how can I seed the form with the **workshop_id** (i.e. the FK relation) in a hidden form field? Obviously because the form hasn't been submitted yet, there is no FK relation yet. But in the URL I have the **kwarg** of `Workshop` **slug**. I can hard-code the `workshop_id` as a `Hidden()` crispy-forms field on a per workshop basis, but this is totally unDRY. Any ideas? I don't think I can use the `select_related()` or `prefetch_related()` methods on the model in **urls.py**, so maybe I have to somehow get both models into the form view somehow?

I don't feel like this is an edge-case scenario, and I am sure someone else has had a similar app workflow.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

After further research it appears that I can do this, using [Django Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/). Not figured out exactly how yet..... hints welcome.

Comment: You got the slug, right? Why don't you use it in your view to get the PK before you save anything? Why do you need to pass it in your form?

Comment: That sounds right. Where exactly would I use that in my view? I need to pass the PK in the form so I know which `Workshop` this `WorkshopAttendee` is applying to. Does that make sense?

Comment: Do I create a `get()` method in my `WorkshopAttendeeFormView`? That seems like the place to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was overly complicating this.

All I needed to do was modify the `form_valid` method for Django's GCBV `FormView` to this:

**workshop/views.py**

```python
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from workshop.models import Workshop, WorkshopAttendee
from workshop.forms import WorkshopAttendeeForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class WorkshopAttendeeFormView(FormView):

    def form_valid(self, form):

        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.workshop = Workshop.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])[0]
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Which basically does not save the form on submit, but instead overrides it and first updates the object it is about to save (the `WorkshopAttendee` object) with the relevant `Workshop` (based on the Workshop slug field, which is unique), **then** saves the updated object (`self.object.save`) and kicks me to the success url.

Big thanks to @init3 for his helpful pointers. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass the PK - you got it already in your URL as the slug.

So let's say this is your URL: http://example.com/workshops/awesome-workshop-slug/sign_in/
Your `urls.py` should look like this:

```
url(r'^workshop/(?P<workshop_slug>\w+)/sign_in/$',
        # ../workshops/awesome-workshop-slug/sign_in/
        view = 'workshop_signin',
        name = 'workshop-signin',
    ),
```

Ok, in your `views.py` you're able to do this:

```
@login_required
def workshop_signin(request, workshop_slug, template='workshop/sign_in.html'):
    """Register user to workshop."""
    form = WorkshopForm()
    workshop = Workshop.objects.filter(slug=workshop_slug)[0]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WorkshopForm(request.POST, instance=workshop)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.info(request, 'Yay!')


    kwargs = {
        'workshop_form': form,
    }
    return render_to_response(template, kwargs, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

*untested quick and dirty code

Comment: Thanks @init3, this has got me moving in the right direction. Unfortunately I can't use your code as is - I am using Django's Generic CBVs throughout, although this has got me poking around in the right [Django source file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py)

Comment: better than nothing - glad I could help a little bit :)

Comment: You got me moving in the right direction with my problem solving, so upvoting you. Cheers.